# styling of sticky posts wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

The added code correctly adds the three recent sticky notes, but I want to style the three sticky notes differently, not in a line. Can someone tell me how I can reference each sticky post differently. I know the code is a little wrong as it assigns a table to each sticky post whereas I want to add each post as elements of the same table

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if(is_home() && !is_paged()) { ?>
<?php query_posts(array('post__in'=>get_option('sticky_posts'))); 
   $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
   rsort($sticky);
   $sticky = array_slice( $sticky, 0, 3);
query_posts( array( 'post__in' => $sticky, 'caller_get_posts' => 1 ) ); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="95%">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top">


<div class="masthead-1" style="float: left;">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() && !is_attachment() ) : ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="mast11" style="opacity: 0.5;"></div>
              <div class="mast12">
                <h1 class="lbl2"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><div style="clear:both"></div></h1>
              </div>
    </div></td></table>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need to know is the number of the sticky post (1st, 2nd or 3rd), just add a variable which you increment at the end of the `while` loop.

```php
<?php $i = 0; while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
<!-- do whatever you want to do here, using $i as a reference to which post you're currently working with -->
<?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

anyway You can use a class wrapper on the outside

```
<div class="specialsticky">

Your wordpress loop here

</div>
```

and use

`.specialsticky table:nth-child(#) {`

to target them each differently

The other way to do this is

in your table tag inside your loop

```
<table class="specialsticky-<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="95%">
```

and then your tables will have a spcial post id attached to creating a new class style for each new entry

`.specialsticky-192 {` will target a post id of 192

Comment: Provided that **only** CSS styling is required, then your first option is definitely the way to go yes. I skim-read the question as requiring *bespoke* markup for each sticky, which isn't really a CSS-only solution.

I'm not convinced that the second option would be much help, as if the sticky notes are frequently changing, then all the styling will be lost, not to mention a headache to have that many CSS rules for each individual post... But I suppose the OP might have been looking at that as a solution!

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a silly question but,using your first option the css can be changed but would I be able to place each sticky post in a different cell of a table?

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question here.. in your original question. to put them all inside table cells Move `<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="95%">
        <tr>` out of the loop and same with the closing tags

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear in the question but,I've mentioned in the question that the code puts them each in separate tables whereas I would like to put each in different cells of the same table

Comment: it is best to use a div wrapper and completely remove your tables.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how this could be done?